# Read data from XML using python

Tags: python, xml

I have data received from web like this:

```
<collective2>
    <status>OK</status>
        <positionstatus>
        <calctime>2017-10-17 03:25:57:000</calctime>
        <symbol>AA</symbol>
        <position>102</position>
        <averagecost>48.86</averagecost>
    </positionstatus>
</collective2>
```

Any Help how to read it. for example get 'OK' ,... Also 'AA'
Thanks in advance.

I have tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data1 = ET.fromstring(data)
ok = data1.get('status')
```

Comment: which libraries have you tried to parse the XML?

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: according to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree, an ElementTree object has no `get` method. try using `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving a lot of information on what you need exactly, but simply reading the first few paragraphs of the [xml.etree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) should have told you that the following code provides you with the results you are asking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')

print(tree.find('status').text)                         # OK
print(tree.find('positionstatus').find('symbol').text)  # AA
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method:

```
>>> from lxml import html as HTML
>>> data1 = HTML.fromstring(data)
print data1.xpath('//status')[0].text
OK
>>> print data1.xpath('//symbol')[0].text
AA
```